# Passing JSON-like parameters in coffeescript

Tags: json, coffeescript

I'm trying to do I few things with the github API written via coffeescript. I'm fairly new to it and I'm having trouble with this block.

```
getRepos: (user)->
    this.github.repos.getFromUser(
        user: user,
        type: "all",
        sort: "updated",
        direction: "desc"
        (err,res)-> console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
    )
```

Currently, it's compiling to

```
 getRepos: function(user) {
  return this.github.repos.getFromUser({
   user: user
   }, {
   type: "all",
   sort: "updated",
   direction: "desc"
    }, function(err, res) {
   return console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
 });
```

Whereas I don't want the extra brackets after user:user, that is it should look like this:

```
getRepos: function(user) {
  return this.github.repos.getFromUser({
    user: user,
    type: "all",
    sort: "updated",
    direction: "desc"
  }, function(err, res) {
  return console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

What am I missing with coffeescript?

Edit: Here's the full code

```
GitHubApi = require("node-github");

gitLoader = 
github: new GitHubApi({
    version: "3.0.0",
    timeout: 5000
}); 
authenticate: ->
    this.github.authenticate({
        type: "basic",
        username: username,
        password: password
    })
getRepos: (user)->
    this.github.repos.getFromUser(
        user: user,
        type: "all",
        sort: "updated",
        direction: "desc"
        (err,res)-> console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
    )
getFollowers: ->
    this.github.user.getFollowingFromUser(
        user: "example",
        (err, res)->console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    )
```

Edit 2: Think it must have been a spacing issue of some sort. When I copy pasted the copy here that was copied from editor, it compiled correctly. = /

Comment: Can't reproduct it with your code. [link](http://goo.gl/IlEQw)

Comment: Me either - check your spacing, and also note you don't need commas to separate those object properties.   You can experiment here: http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js

Comment: Yeah I get your incorrect output if I put an extra space in front of `user: ...`

Comment: Hmm. Managed to get it working. Must have been a spacing issue of some sort...

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is an extra white space(probably a tab) before "user:"

If you make sure there are only spaces it will compile as expected.

```
getRepos: (user) ->
    this.github.repos.getFromUser(
        user: user,
        type: "all",
        sort: "updated",
        direction: "desc"
        (err,res) -> console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This look like an white space issue.

You also could omit a few other things, so you code would look like:

```
getRepos: (user) ->
    @github.repos.getFromUser
        user: user
        type: "all"
        sort: "updated"
        direction: "desc"
        (err, res) -> console.log JSON.stringify res
```